# Geometric intuition for why the slope of the tangent at the y-intercept of $y=b^x$ is $\ln(b)$?

Tags: calculus, slope

I understand how to prove that algebraically, but it's really amazing how the slope is exactly $\ln(b)$. My question is how can I develop a geometric feeling for it, or is it even possible to do so?

Comment: This is always kind of a weird subject because how you proceed depends very much on where you start, and there are several more or less equally difficult places where you can start. In terms of this particular question, the issue is "what do you mean by $\ln(x)$?" Is it defined as the inverse of $e^x$? Is it defined as $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$?

Comment: l don't see anything special about it.

Comment: @Ian Hi, thanks for commenting! y=ln(x) in this case means that e^y = x.

Comment: Do you know any calculus?

Comment: "y=ln(x) in this case means that e^y = x."  And what does $e$ mean? and what does $e^y$ mean if $y$ isn't a rational number?.... This is subtle, and hard, and required the development of calculus but definition of $e$ and the definition of $\ln x$ and the definition of $e^x$ and $b^x = e^{x\ln b}$ *all* makes this result fall out by definition.

Answer (score 1):

If slope is $\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac {b^{x_1}-b^x}{x_1 - x}$ where $x_1$ is really really close to $x$.

If we let $x_h = x+h$ and $h$ is a really really small number then

slope is $\frac {b^{x+h} - b^{x}}{(x+h)-x} = \frac {b^xb^h -b^x}h= b^x \frac {b^h -1}h$

The value $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac {b^h-1}h$ is a constant value depending only on the value of $b$ and has nothing to do with $x$.

---

Now how surprised would you be if I told you $\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {b^h-1}h = \ln b$?

.... okay, maybe that is surprising.

But consider let define the function as $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {b^h-1}h$.

We can not that for small values of $b$ that  $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b)$ is small and for large values of $b$ that $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b)$ is large.

So there must be some number where $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b) = 1$.

So lets define a  number $E$ to be  *DEFINED* to be the number where $\operatorname{BEATSME}(E) = 1$.

Would it surprise you if I told you that $E = e$ where $e$ is Euler's number?

Okay, most classes define $e$ as $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n$.  Okay... if we define $e$ that way what is $\operatorname{BEATSME}(e)$?

$e=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac 1n)^n = \lim_\limits{h\to \infty}(1 + h)^{\frac 1h}$.

And $\operatorname{BEATSME}(e) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {e^g-1}h = \lim_\limits{h\to \infty}\frac {(\lim_\limits{h\to \infty}(1 + h)^{\frac 1h})^h-1}h=$

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {((1+h)^{\frac 1h})^h-1}h=$

$\lim _\limits{h\to 0^+}{(1+h)^1 - 1}h = \lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {(1+h)-1}h=\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac hh = 1$.

So that's it . $\operatorname{BEATSME}(e) = 1$.

---

Okay, but what is $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b)$ in general?

Okay  $\operatorname{BEATSME}(b) = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac{b^h -1}h= \ln b$.

Why?
Let $e^K = b$.

Then $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (1+\frac 1n)^{nK} = b$.

Let $(1+\frac 1n)^{nK} =B$ for a very large $n$.

Then $(1+\frac 1n)^K = B^{\frac 1n}$

By binomial expansion $(1+\frac 1n)^K \approx 1 + K\frac 1n$ for  large $n$.

So $1+K\frac 1n = B^{\frac 1n}$

$K = n(B^{\frac 1n}-1)$.

Replace $n$ with $\frac 1h$ and we get $K = \frac {B^h-1}h$ and so the the

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} \frac {b^h -1}h = \ln h$.

---

Whew.  So the slope of the tangent line of $b^x$ is $b^x\lim_\limits{h\to 0} \frac {b^h-1}h = b^x\ln b$.

And at $x=0$ that is $\ln b$ exactly.